# ProgressDialog Box Dummy Timer

Tags: android, timer, delay, progressdialog

Hey guys i wanted to ask if i can add dummy timer to my progress box.

I want my progress box to prompt user to enter his current location then his destination so when the app starts it will prompt him to enter his username, after 2 seconds of msg displaying the msg will dissapear. How can i implement his

code so far:

```
int timer = 0;
ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
progressDialog.setMessage("Enter Current Location");
progressDialog.show();

// do { ++timer; } while ( timer != 500 ); // hiding after 500 iterations
progressDialog.hide();
```

The do while loop doesn't work for me, so are there other options?

Comment: Please dont make my dialogs spontaneously disappear...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its called ***delay*** and not dummy timer.

To add delay, add this code after `progressDialog.show()` function.

1500 ms delay (1.5 seconds);

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }   }, 1500);
```

or 3000 ms delay (3 seconds);

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }   }, 3000);
```

and remove `progressDialog.dismiss()` from end of your code after adding any of the above one.

Cheers.